# How we can convert a STL file to OpenSCAD?

Tags: qt

I have one STL file and i will load STL file in and need to convert STL file to openscad.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QT itself does not provide any means to work with either SCAD or STL files, other than standard I/O. To achieve such conversion yourself, you would have to fiddle with the file formats. Alternatively you can look at OpenSCAD's source code as it is open-source and is able to do this conversion, possibly even providing libraries for this. However, OpenSCAD is GPL, so you have to consider if this complies with your product's license.